"have a better imagination" or "have better imagination"


Reading fairy tales allows children to have better imagination.




Reading fairy tales allows children to have a better imagination.


According to OD, imagination can be both countable and uncountable.
Does this mean I can use either form of the word, or does it mean it depends on the context?
If the latter is the case, in which contexts do we use imagination in its singular form, and, plural form?

When I was writing the last sentence, I suddenly wanted to try using the gapping comma, a completely new aspect of the English language that I had just discovered. Did I use it correctly?

To use the gapping comma here (after and), we should use a semi-colon before and:
...singular form; and, plural form?.

Thanks a lot! Can we use it for academic writing?

better imagination is not great. The comparative use of better: He has a better imagination than I do.

Instead of asking a new question, you might want to deal with what you have already asked...

Oh, I have seen the answers to this question and they've been consistent, so I have already drawn a conclusion. I forgot to accept an answer, though.

Why did you dig so deep? XD

better imagination is not great in the OP's sentence.
The comparative use of better: He has a better imagination than I do.

Reading allows children to develop their imagination (or imaginations).

Mass nouns (uncountable) can be used in the singular to refer to more than a single person.
Generally, we don't use imagination with an s, though one could.
For example:

Reading stories helps children develop their imagination. By reading
the story and looking at the pictures, their little brains will
receive many excellent ideas, and they will be able to predict what is
going on in the story and what will going to happen next or come up
with their own endings.

develop their imagination
The dictionary says countable but it is most often used in the singular.

We usually speak of a person's imagination in a countable way, as a quality which everyone possesses. We say "He has a vivid imagination" in the same way as we say "He has a good memory", meaning 'the ability to imagine/remember things'.

This is the correct example: Reading fairy tales allows children to have a better imagination.
This is because "imagination' is both an uncountable (mass noun) and a count noun. Mass nouns or uncountable nouns do not have plural forms.

With count nouns - use a/an/the.
With uncountable nouns - use 'the' or no article.

Imagination from Britannica
Description on articles
